# several maps and images in a column like shape

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

I would like to have 4 maps in a row and some images of it below. The best I came with is

```
\begin{align}\label{sumary isomorphisms}
(\textrm{Im} H, [,]) \rightarrow \mathfrak{su}(2) \rightarrow & \mathfrak{so}(3) \rightarrow \R^3 \rightarrow (\textrm{Im} H, \cdot)\\
i\mapsto  i \sigma_3 \mapsto & 2 J_x \mapsto 2 e_1 \mapsto 2i \\
j\mapsto  -i \sigma_2 \mapsto & 2J_y \mapsto 2 e_2 \mapsto 2j \\
k\mapsto  -i\sigma_1 \mapsto & 2 J_z \mapsto 2 e_3 \mapsto 2k
\end{align}
```

I would like to know if I can use several "&"´s in order to force the vertical alignments. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative possibility with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im} % \Im is preempted
\DeclareMathOperator{\su}{\mathfrak{su}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\so}{\mathfrak{so}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{summary-isomorphisms}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0pt]
(\im H, [\,,\,]) \arrow[r] & \su(2) \arrow[r] & \so(3) \arrow[r] & \R^3 \arrow[r] & (\im H, {\cdot}) \\
i\arrow[r,mapsto] & i\sigma_3 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2J_x \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2e_1 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2i \\
j\arrow[r,mapsto] & -i\sigma_2 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2J_y \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2e_2 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2j \\
k\arrow[r,mapsto] & -i\sigma_1 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2 J_z \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2e_3 \arrow[r,mapsto] & 2k
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about using an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
    \[ \begin{array}{r*{7}{c}l}
        (\text{Im} H, [,]) & \rightarrow & \mathfrak{su}(2) & \rightarrow & \mathfrak{so}(3) & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}^3 & \rightarrow & (\text{Im} H, \cdot) \\
        i & \mapsto & i\sigma_3 & \mapsto & 2J_x & \mapsto & 2e_1 & \mapsto & 2i \\
        j & \mapsto & -i\sigma_2 & \mapsto & 2J_y & \mapsto & 2e_2 & \mapsto & 2j \\
        k & \mapsto & -i\sigma_1 & \mapsto & 2J_z & \mapsto & 2e_3 & \mapsto & 2k
    \end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing `*7c` to `*{7}{c}`: I know that the “unbraced” version works, but it could be misleading for beginners.